# How to find out Hidden Sheet Names in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel

How do I find out the hidden excel sheet name using ADO(OLEDB) in C#?

In My Excel workbook there are a lot of sheets. Only one Excel sheet is in hidden mode. I need to find out the names of hidden sheets. My code finds both hidden and visible sheets.

This is my code to find excel sheet names for all sheets. Is it possible/can any one tell me how to find out hidden excel sheet names without using Interop services in C#?

```
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;;IMEX=1;HDR=YES\"";
query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}", fileName + "]");
OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, objCon);
OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(objCmd);
adap.FillSchema(dtExcelSchema, SchemaType.Mapped);
adap.Fill(dsExecelData);
```

Comment: As a side note, when the connection is closed, each call to `.Fill` will open and close the connection. To load the data and schema in one .Fill, something like: `adap.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey; adap.Fill(dsExecelData);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sheet name ends with an underscore (_) then its hidden.  Regular sheet names will end with a dollar sign ($).

Comment: Can you post an example of the data in dsExecelData?

Comment: not working i am getting all the names which ends with $(both regular and hidden one).

Comment: This is not working for me too. Where did you even get this information?

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://july-code.blogspot.mx/2008/02/hidden-worksheet-in-excel-file.html) works for me

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

...

Excel.Application xlAppSource = null;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBookSource = null;


// workbook
xlWorkBookSource = xlAppSource.Workbooks.Open(xlsFilePath, 0, false, 5, null, null, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, null, true, false, 0, true, false, false);

// here is your list
List<int> list = getHiddenSheetsIndexes(xlWorkBookSource.Worksheets);

...

private List<int> getHiddenSheetsIndexes(Excel.Sheets sheets) 
{
    // return
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

    int index = 0;

    foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in sheets)
    {
        index++;

        if (sheet.Visible == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetHidden)
            indexes.Add(index);

    }

    // return
    return indexes;
}
```

Comment: Office interop is not supported on server side, note ASP.NET tag in OP question